# maintaining session on different routes

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

How do you maintain session between route.

I have 3 routes

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var question = require('./routes/question');


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/question',question);
```

on top of the 3 js file is this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
```

this created a new router thus losing the session i guess?

within users, i use passport to create a login system, by its default serializer the user information is saved under req.user but only accessible within users route.

I would like to use the session within routes(index) and question route. How do i solve this?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that you have defined each request specific route in its separate file. 
Then you donot need to define these line again in main file.

> var express = require('express');
>   var router = express.Router();

```
app.use(passport.session());
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
// passport.js provides this method req.isAuthenticated()) 
if (req.isAuthenticated()) 
   return next();
else
// Return error content: res.jsonp(...) or redirect: res.redirect('/login')
}
```

Here, you can define your strategy to check routes. If it is authenticate then disclose user related information.

```
app.use('/', ensureAuthenticated, routes);
```

Comment: i have this router.use(passport.session()); within users.js is this possible to use it somewhere else, or I have to move it to app.js. Thanks mabc

Comment: you can not do router.use(passport.session());
You need to declare it in app.js after declaring express session.
And check each route url and show your specific information on selected route

Comment: move everything to app, and passing app to router works. thanks

Comment: Do you guys a tutorial i can follow, i have been trying to find one that does not use mongoose, but i cant find one.